# How can I initialise group names in Django every time the program runs?

Tags: django, django-users

I have this code and I want it to just create the groups every time the program runs so that if the database is deleted it will still be a sufficient program itself and someone won't have to create groups again, do you know an easy way to do this?

```
system_administrator = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='system_administrator')
    manager = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='manager')
    travel_advisor = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='travel_advisor')
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Comment: You don't have to run **`get_or_create`** every time, because it's stored in DB. If you want to populate/create Groups during migration, use [**Data Migration**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) functionality. The funny part, If the *Database is deleted accidentally* you should worry about other relevant  data than this merely a *three row creation*

Answer (score 3):

If you lose your DB, you'd have to rerun migrations on a fresh db before the program could run again. So I think `data migrations` might be a good solution for this? A data migration, is a migration that runs python code to alter the data in the DB, not the schema as a normal migration does.

You could do something like this:

In a new migration file (you can run `python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname` to create an empty migration file for an app)

```
def generate_groups(apps, schema_editor):

    Group = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Group')
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name="system_administrator")
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name="manager")
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name="travel_advisor")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', 'previous migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(generate_groups),
    ]
```

Worth reading the docs on this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the [`ready`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method of one of your apps.

```py
class YourApp(Appconfig):

    def ready(self):
        # important do the import inside the method
        from something import Group

        Group.objects.get_or_create(name='system_administrator')
        Group.objects.get_or_create(name='manager')
        Group.objects.get_or_create(name='travel_advisor')
```

The problem with the data migrations approach is that it is useful for populate the database the first time. But if the groups are deleted once the data migration has run, you will need to populate them again.

Also remember that `get_or_create` return a tuple.

```py
group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='manager')
# group if an instance of Group
# created is a boolean
```

Comment: So do I need  to create an external app to do this?

Comment: You can put it in any application you've created in the project.

Comment: This is a bit tricky since you need to be aware that this is done every time you run the app - also for tests which sometimes run this method more than once. For the code above, it seems fine, but it's something to keep in mind